# Binding nullable datetime in MVC with String format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am unable to solve problem from last two days.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myObject.dateAssign, String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}"))
```

here, dateAssign is nullable datetime. it may be or maybe not have value.

i am keep getting following  error

```
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

please give me some hint or direction

Comment: "" is not date, ?? will throw error, as DateTime is valuetype and string is reference type

Answer (score 4):

`String.Format()` needs a second argument [(see documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) - in your case your date.

Have a look at [this page](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for date formats.

Then you would write something like

```
@Html.TextBox(model => String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", model.myObject.dateAssign))
```

Or, if you want to use `@Html.TextBoxFor`, you can annotate your property like this:

```
// in your model:
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode= true]
DateTime? dateAssign { get; set; }  

// and in your view:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myObject.dateAssign)
```

Comment: here date is nullable

Comment: i tried but that changes the error to "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: `String.Format` works with `null`, too. It's just empty, then. To your second question: Replace `@Html.TextBoxFor` with `@Html.TextBox`. That should work.

Comment: The [DisplayFormat] attribute is only used in EditorFor/DisplayFor, and not by the raw HTML APIs like TextBoxFor and also DisplayFormat works when we set ApplyFormatInEditMode= true in dataanotations